# Offline storage for PDF iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I like to provide an offline storage option to my current PDF reader application. I just like to know what are the best possible ways to store an PDF offline for persistent storage. I am planning to use CoreData but I don't know it will be overkill for my project or not. Can someone please help me to find quick way for persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

If depends on how this storage fits on your application. If you do not have a current database system, then creating a database to keep a list of PDF documents is an overkill. Just create a directory and read the files contained in that directory. Check the documentation of NSFileManager for help with creating files and directories: [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you already have a database, do not save the pdf files in the database. If using core data, use the "Store in external record file" feature, which is available on iOS 5 and above.